# WPB ListBox bind to control inside a class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have a WPF ListBox of Grids that I create as follows:

I define the listbox in XAML with a simple declaration as follows:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListbox" >
</ListBox>
```

In code, I dynamically create an arbitrary number of Grid items (System.Windows.Controls.Grid), and I add them to the ListBox.  Something like:

```
foreach (MyDataType myItem in MyDataList)
{
   Grid newGrid = new Grid();
   // Code that sets the properties and values of the grid, based on myItem

   MyListbox.Items.Add(newGrid);
}
```

This works great, and everything looks the way that I want it to.

Now, I've decided that in my ListBox, I also want to store a reference to the actual myItem object, so that I can reference it later.

My idea was to create a new class like:

```
public class ListGridItemNode
{
    public MyDataType theItem;
    public Grid theGrid;
    public ListGridItemNode(MyDataType inItem, Grid inGrid)
    {
        theItem = inItem;
        theGrid = inGrid;
    }
}
```

And then change my code to:

```
foreach (MyDataType myItem in MyDataList)
{
   Grid newGrid = new Grid();
   // Code that sets the properties and values of the grid, based on myItem

   MyListbox.Items.Add(new ListGridItemNode(myItem,newGrid));
}
```

Of course, now my listbox instead of displaying the grids, just displays the text "MyApp.ListGridItemNode".

My question is: How do I tell the ListBox to go a level deeper and display the actual Grids inside of each ListGridItemNode object?

I suspect that this has something to do with bindings, but I can't find any examples that work the way that I'm doing it.  Most of what I'm finding only shows binding to a string within an object, not an entire control.

Comment: The reason that you don't find documentation on this is that *this isn't intended to be done*. You create controls, which bind to data, using item templates to determine *how* the data is displayed. You shouldn't be dynamically adding to the items control like that.

Comment: Do not create UI elements in code. Instead, create a proper DataTemplate for your ListBox items. Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Actually this is strange, the other way around (ListBoxes in a Grid) is understandable. How are you going to deal with the blue focus over your grids ? If you need a collection of grids, wrap them inside an ItemsControl or a StackPanel for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use the `Tag` property of the Grid object?

```
newGrid.Tag = myItem;
```

Then later:

```
Grid grid; // obtain Grid object somehow
MyItem myItem = (MyItem) grid.Tag;
```

Comment: That's a great alternate solution, and it worked for me.  If nobody else has a solution to my original idea within a few days, I'll accept this one.